# How to show current time in textbox in android

Tags: android

In my application I need to show current date and time in a texview. The text view should be set with updated for every minute. I dont want to display seconds. Can any one please help me.

Comment: Simple use Date Class with the TimerTask Class.

Answer (score 3):

```
String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

You get Date by using

```
String mydate =     java.text.DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

And You can set This Value in TextView By Using,

```
TextView textView=  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
textView.setText(mydate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy this into your class.

```
private RefreshHandler mRedrawHandler = new RefreshHandler();

class RefreshHandler extends Handler {
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
String curDateTime = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(curDateTime);
sleep(60000); }

public void sleep(long delayMillis) {
this.removeMessages(0);
sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
    }
}
```

Then in onCreate, call mRedrawHandler.sleep(delay);